# ASP.NET Core doesn't service filenames with which contain %20 (space)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Files which contain a %20 (space character) in it's name doesn't get downloaded/opened when accessed via url.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create an empty ASP.NET Core Web API project from Visual Studio.
2. Add `StaticFiles` package to the project.
3. Add the following code to the `Startup.cs` `Configure` method

   ```
   app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
   {          
       FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"StaticFiles")),
           RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles"),
           EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
   });
   ```
4. Add a folder named "StaticFiles" to the Directory.
5. Add any file with '%20' in filename . Ex:- 'FileName%20WithPercentEncodedSpace.pdf'
6. Run the application. Open http://localhost:19390/StaticFiles in the browser.
7. File list will contain `FileName%20WithPercentEncodedSpace.pdf`. But it won't be open when clicked on.
8. Also add the following code in `Web.config` for allowing double escape sequence:

   ```
   <security>
       <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
   </security>
   ```

I also tried http://localhost:19390/StaticFiles/FileName%2520WithPercentEncodedSpace.pdf. But it also doesn't work!

Comment: does he filename actually conatin %20 or space ?

Comment: yes ! 'FileName%20WithPercentEncodedSpace.pdf'

Comment: %20 is a space; basically file name is UrlEncoded. You did not say where you get that file. Ideally, you should UrlDecode it back before saving that file to file system.

Comment: Well, when calling it with  http://localhost:19390/StaticFiles/FileName%2520WithPercentEncodedSpace.pdf it works for me (ASP.NET Core 1.1). Maybe its a bug with 1.0 which as been fixed in 1.1?

Comment: @Win I am getting the file from an external system . So I cannot UrlDecode the file name

Comment: @Tseng I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1 . But doesn't work. Can you please share your code if that works.

Comment: Same as above. But only works when directly calling the link, not via the file browser (it still encodes the links wrongly). You may want to fill a bug/issue about that here https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles though